# fsockopen - how to detect end of message?

Tags: php, sockets, pop3, fsockopen

I have code:

```
$f = fsockopen('mail.myserver.com', 110); //POP3
echo fgets($f, 4096) . '<hr>';
fputs($f, "USER login@myserver.com\r\n");
echo fgets($f) . '<br>';
fputs($f, "PASS mypass\r\n");
echo fgets($f) . '<br>';
fputs($f, "LIST\r\n");
echo fgets($f) . '<br>';
fputs($f, "RETR 1\r\n");
```

So far so good, but then I have a loop to receive the whole message:

```
while (!feof($f)) 
{
echo fgets($f, 1280);
}
```

and it takes forever because the script waits for timeouts to kick in—it NEVER detects EOF by itself.

How can I detect EOF and break the loop before it times out? If I use telnet then everything works—somehow telnet clients know when to stop receiving.

Comment: You can always use (http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php).

Comment: @PawełMalisak: I can't, it is rather rare extension and is not available on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

> **Warning** If a connection opened by fsockopen() wasn't closed by the server, feof() will hang. To workaround this, see below example:

On: [feof](http://php.net/feof)

The workaround essentially waits `default_socket_timeout` and then terminates the while-loop.

Comment: But how do telnet clients know when the message is complete?

Comment: I guess telnet does detect the `eof`?

Answer (score 1):

[Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) may provide a better alternative to handling timeouts/hangs.